# Select item from the browser context menu

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have a Chrome extension which adds telephony functionality to the browser and I am trying to write a test scenario where the user right clicks on a telephone number and then clicks the Dial option from the context menu.

I have seen many workarounds for this and used many myself in the past, but in this scenario I really need to click the context menu item. If I try doing a click offset the item under the context menu is clicked instead.

Can a context menu item selection be done through the webdriver?

[image]

Comment: This is not the conventional _context menu_ but _Chrome_ browsers **native** context menu.

Comment: Do some research on AutoIT.

Comment: Selenium can't see the context menu, it can only see the page itself. Each context menu will be browser specific and will likely be different. You can do things like shortcuts and arrow up/down, but those are fragile.

Comment: I'm thinking this might get you headed in the right direction where you launch a desktop session and then run tests inside of it. Kinda similar to a selenium's ability to harness browser elements, this allows harnessing of some Windows elements.
https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver#creating-a-desktop-session

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can build an action with the `contextClick()`:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);        
actions.contextClick().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
```

It is in `Java` but you can easly implement something like this in C#.
It will select something from the context menu, you just need to add some more `ARROW_DOWN`'s

Comment: Thanks. This is not a great solution, but it does work. below is out C# code for resolving this if anyone is interested:

    Actions contextMenuDial = new Actions(_driver);
    IWebElement elementToRightClick = MainPage.txtSearch(_driver);
    contextMenuDial.DoubleClick(elementToRightClick).Build().Perform();
    contextMenuDial.ContextClick(elementToRightClick).Build().Perform();
    contextMenuDial.SendKeys(Keys.Up).SendKeys(Keys.Up).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectButtonElement = WindowsDriver.FindElementByAccessibilityId(SelectButtonAutomationId);

Actions action = new Actions(WindowsDriver);

action.ContextClick(selectButtonElement).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Down).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```